# HOW TO USE JavascriptExecutor in Microsoft edge using java and selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, microsoft-edge-chromium

We have automation project we need to click menu items we use this below code

((JavascriptExecutor) test.getDriver()).executeScript("mCLICK(arguments[0]);", substr);

its is working well in chrome browser we want migrate to edge . we are running the same code in
micro soft Edge browser  it's  giving the below error

Exception class:org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException
the reason is:org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Function is not a constructor.

Pls advise

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for click event for edge browser i put condition based on the browser

if(!browser.equals("edge")) {
String substr = child.getAttribute("substr");

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)
```

test.getDriver()).executeScript("mCLICK(arguments[0]);", substr);
}
else
{
test.getDriver().findElement(By.name(items[0])).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
test.getDriver().findElement(By.name(items[1])).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
test.getDriver().findElement(By.name(items[2])).click();
}